# How to execute this PostgreSQL join without using ANY()?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL tables. Table 1 has a column which is boolean, Table 2 has a column which is an array of one or both booleans:

```
--Table 1
id1  bool1
A    t
B    f
A    f
B    t   

--Table 2
id2  bool2
A    {"t", "f"}
B    {"f"}
A    {"t", "f"}
B    {"t"}
```

What I want is, a join of the two tables on all rows where the IDs match, and any value in `bool2` matches the value in `bool1`. I can make this happen on my local computer with

```
select * from table1
left join table2 on id1=id2 and bool1 = any(bool2)
```

However, my company uses a third-party system which does not support arrays in SQL. The arrays have to be cast into text columns. So how do I make this work without using `any()`?

Comment: But the application doesn't actually need to know anything about arrays in order to run that query. You are not passing an array as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

With booleans, you're safe just using substring matching since you won't have to worry about unexpected characters showing up. Something like

```sql
WHERE bool2 LIKE ('%' || bool1 || '%')
```

or

```sql
WHERE substr(bool2,bool1::text) IS NOT NULL
```